# Not able to add my provider in side the index.js file in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have a MovieDetails.js component and context(name is MyContext) and provider (name is MyProvider).
MyProvider component has list of Movies. I would like to render that list into MovieDetails component.so,
in index.js file imported the  MovieDetails and MyContext components as below

```
import {MovieDetails} from './Assignment/Topic12Assignment1/MovieDetails'  
import { MyProvider } from './Assignment/Topic12Assignment1/MyContext';
```

try to render MovieDetails component as below code.

```
<MyProvider>
ReactDOM.render(<MovieDetails />,document.getElementById('root'));
</MyProvider>
```

returning error as below

[image]

not understanding where did i miss anything?

below code is MovieDetails component

```
import React, { useState, useContext }  from 'react'
import {MyContext} from './MyContext'

export const MovieDetails = () => {
  const [movies,setMovies] = useContext(MyContext);
  debugger
    return(
        <React.Fragment>
      {
              <li>{movies.length}</li>
      }
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

Below code for MyContext file

```
import React, {useState,createContext} from 'react'
//import AppReducer from './AppReducer'

export const MyContext = createContext();
export const MyProvider = (props) => {
    const [movies,setMovies] = useState([ {MovieID:1,MovieName:'Rangastalam',LeadActor:'RamCharan',LeadActree:'Samantha'
    ,YearOfRelease:2019,Language:'Telugu',Collections:'200Crores'},
   {MovieID:2,MovieName:'AVP',LeadActor:'AlluArun',LeadActree:'Puja'
    ,YearOfRelease:2020,Language:'Telugu',Collections:'400Crores'},
   {MovieID:3,MovieName:'Saaho',LeadActor:'Prabhas',LeadActree:'Shraddha'
    ,YearOfRelease:2020,Language:'Telugu',Collections:'300Crores'}]);

    return(
<MyContext.MyProvider value = {'testomg'}>{props.children}</MyContext.MyProvider>
    );
};
```

index file code

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

import {MovieDetails} from './Assignment/Topic12Assignment1/MovieDetails'
import { MyProvider } from './Assignment/Topic12Assignment1/MyContext';

<MyProvider>
ReactDOM.render(<MovieDetails />,document.getElementById('root'));
</MyProvider>
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

app file code

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Check whether you have export `MovieDetails ` and  `MyContext` correctly. Also check the way you import files in `index.js` is matching  with the way you export files.

Comment: can you post the code in `MovieDetails` and `MyProvider` as well?

Comment: i updated my query details..could you please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in `MyProvider` file

```
return (
  <MyContext.MyProvider value={"testomg"}>{props.children}</MyContext.MyProvider>
);
```

should be

```
return (
  <MyContext.Provider value={"testomg"}>{props.children}</MyContext.Provider>
);
```

Also, in `index.js` file this should be corrected

```
<MyProvider>
ReactDOM.render(<MovieDetails />,document.getElementById('root'));
</MyProvider>
```

should be

```
ReactDOM.render(
<MyProvider>
  <MovieDetails />
</MyProvider>
,document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: yes it's App.js file but later i did change code in index.js file as below  and app.js file as initial version.

<MyProvider>
ReactDOM.render(<MovieDetails />,document.getElementById('root'));
</MyProvider>

Comment: @Surya Updated comment above.

Comment: Thank you but even after changing code as you mentioned still getting same error..it's showing error in index

Comment: @Surya Oh, I think I missed one more point, updated again